# Get Facebook user ID with android SDK 4.0

Tags: android, facebook, sdk

How can I get the Facebook User ID with the Facebook Android SDK 4.0?

Here is my code that doesn't work:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_firstlogin);

    CallbackManager cm;
    LoginButton     lb;

    cm = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
    lb = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.facebook_button);
    Log.d(TAG, "Salut les zouzous");
    LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(cm,
            new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>()
            {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult)
                {
                   Log.d(TAG, "Success !");
                    AccessToken tok;
                    tok = AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken();
                    Log.d(TAG, tok.getUserId());
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancel()
                {
                    Log.d(TAG, "On Cancel");
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(FacebookException exception)
                {
                    Log.e(TAG, exception.getMessage());
                }
            });
```

I precise that the

```
 Log.d(TAG, " Success");
```

doesn't print.

There is only the first log who print something, outside the callback.

Sorry for the bad English.

Answer (score 31):

As simple as

```
Profile.getCurrentProfile().getId()
```

This assumes the user is already logged in.

Comment: there's this issue I'm facing with facebook sdk.. please help with it: https://stackoverflow.com/q/46751331/6144372

Answer (score 9):

You will need to do the following

```
 @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
            final AccessToken accessToken = loginResult.getAccessToken();

            GraphRequestAsyncTask request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(accessToken, new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted(JSONObject user, GraphResponse graphResponse) {
                    Log.d(TAG, user.optString("email"));
                    Log.d(TAG, user.optString("name"));
                    Log.d(TAG, user.optString("id"));
                }
            }).executeAsync();
        }
```

Comment: Android Studio dosen't want to auto-import FBUser class. What is the include ?

Comment: Thanks, that compile but that doesn't log anything :(

Comment: its a async request, try to wait for a sec. and try to login again.

Comment: Still doesn't work,
I let you know that i am already logged in the facebook sdk, so when i click on the "Log with facebook" button there is only a little spin for a second then nothing.

Comment: then logout and try again.

Comment: I logout of the facebook app on my phone, then launch my app and retype my passwd, still don't log anythng ...

Comment: try to debug, and find if it goes inside of `onCompleted`

Comment: there's this issue I'm facing with facebook sdk.. please help with it: https://stackoverflow.com/q/46751331/6144372

Answer (score 6):

just use `loginResult.getAccessToken().getUserId()` in **onSuccess()** as

```
@Override
public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {

    Toast.makeText(Login.this, "User ID : "+loginResult.getAccessToken().getUserId(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the Login Button that is provided by Facebook then I think instead of

`LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback()`

you need to use

`lb.registerCallback()`

That could explain why your callback isn't firing at all.

****edit****

If your callback's still aren't firing and you only need the UserID you could go for AccessToken Tracking instead.

Facebook offers an example where you override the onActivityResult method of the Activity/Fragment that you've declared the button in:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

Comment: I would expect at least one of those callback logs to fire once the callback is linked to the button. Everything else in your code looks like it matches up to the example on the Facebook site. That was the only obvious error to me.

Comment: @RomanGrout I've edited my answer with another solution from the docs,  but I've just spotted something else that might be worth trying first. Move the CallbackManager cm line out of onCreate and declare it in the Activity instead so that all methods have access to it.