# Facebook android sdk's 'AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken.getUserId()' method is returning different id from the id retrieved using findmyfbid.com

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk, facebook-access-token

I'm trying to get user's id like this:

```
AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken.getUserId()
```

and it is returning an id like this:

```
1493******22153
```

but when I'm retrieving the id for same user using [findmyfbid.com](https://findmyfbid.com/), I'm getting an id like this:

```
1000******00783
```

Though both ids when used like this `https://facebook.com/id` is opening the same profile successfully in browsers.

Why is this happening and what is the difference between these 2 ids?

Comment: Both users which are on mobile and web are same?

Comment: @MurtazaKhursheedHussain Yes. They both are same.

Comment: As per the documentation, it is retrieving from the current access token which is correct, I don't know what *findmyfbid.com* is using. Try getting id from `Profile.getCurrentProfile().getId()` .  If both ids are same then findmyfbid.com is something else/wrong

Comment: @MurtazaKhursheedHussain I have tried `Profile.getCurrentProfile().getId()` and it is returning the same id as retrieved using `AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken.getUserId()` but the problem is that the functionality which I want to implement is possible only with the id which findmyfbid.com is fetching. See this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/46782419/6144372 Also see the edited question here.

Comment: Found similar thing here, if it can help https://forum.unity.com/threads/facebook-sdk-fb-userid-is-different-from-my-facebook-user-id.247524/

Comment: @MurtazaKhursheedHussain another thing to note is that when I opening this facebook profile in browser and clicking on 'About', this link is coming up in the link bar above: `https://www.facebook.com/***/about?lst=1000******0783%3A1000******0783%3A150****313`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156914/discussion-between-hammad-nasir-and-murtaza-khursheed-hussain).

Comment: @MurtazaKhursheedHussain please reply in chat.