# Facebook messenger chathead is not opening up with the 'AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken().getUserId()' user ID passed into the intent

Tags: android, facebook, android-intent, facebook-android-sdk, facebook-messages

I'm trying to open Facebook Messenger programmatically for specific user using his user ID.

Here's my code:

```
AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
android.view.View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_right_swipe, null);
dialogBuilder.setView(dialogView);
TextView contactForBuyingTxt = dialogView.findViewById(R.id.contact_for_buying_txt);
contactForBuyingTxt.setText("Would you like to contact " + mProfile.getPosterName() + " for buying this product?");
dialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("YES", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("fb-messenger://user/"+mProfile.getPosterID()));
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        mContext.startActivity(intent);
    }
});
dialogBuilder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
        //pass
    }
});
AlertDialog b = dialogBuilder.create();
b.show();
```

Here's Profile.java:

```
public class Profile {

    public Profile() {

    }

    @SerializedName("imageUrl")
    @Expose
    private ArrayList<String> imageUrl;

    @SerializedName("pDescription")
    @Expose
    private String pDescription;

    @SerializedName("pUsedDuration")
    @Expose
    private String pUsedDuration;

    @SerializedName("pPrice")
    @Expose
    private String pPrice;

    @SerializedName("postedAt")
    @Expose
    private String postedAt;

    @SerializedName("pName")
    @Expose
    private String pName;

    @SerializedName("pImage")
    @Expose
    private String pImage;

    @SerializedName("pID")
    @Expose
    private String pID;

    @SerializedName("listingID")
    @Expose
    private String listingID;

    public Profile(ArrayList<String> pImageUrl, String pDescription, String pDuration, String pPrice, String postedAt, String pName, String pUrl, String pID, String listingID) {
        this.imageUrl = pImageUrl;
        this.pDescription = pDescription;
        this.pDuration = pDuration;
        this.pPrice = pPrice;
        this.postedAt = postedAt;
        this.pName = pName;
        this.pImage = pImageUrl;
        this.pID = pID;
        this.listingID = listingID;
    }

    public String getPDescription() {
        return pDescription;
    }

    public void setPDescription(String pDescription) {
        this.pDescription = pDescription;
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getImageUrl() {
        return imageUrl;
    }

    public void setImageUrl(ArrayList<String> imageUrl) {
        this.imageUrl = imageUrl;
    }

    public String getPDuration() {
        return pDuration;
    }

    public void setPDuration(String pDuration) {
        this.pDuration = pDuration;
    }

    public String getPPrice() {
        return pPrice;
    }

    public void setPPrice(String pPrice) {
        this.pPrice = pPrice;
    }

    public String getPostedAt() {
        return postedAt;
    }

    public void setPostedAt(String postedAt) {
        this.postedAt = postedAt;
    }

    public String getPName() {
        return pName;
    }

    public void setPName(String pName) {
        this.pName = pName;
    }

    public String getPImage() {
        return pImage;
    }

    public void setPImage(String pImage) {
        this.pImage = pImage;
    }

    public String getPID() {
        return pID;
    }

    public void setPID(String pID) {
        this.pID = pID;
    }

    public String getListingID() {
        return listingID;
    }

    public void setListingID(String listingID) {
        this.listingID = listingID;
    }
}
```

Please consider this: There are different listings like things in which `mProfile.getPosterName()` is the name of one who posted the listing and `mProfile.getPosterId()` is his facebook id.

This is opening up the chat head but it is not opening it up for a specific user and rather the chat head shows 'Facebook User' as name.

`AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken().getUserId()` one look like this:

`1493******22153`

and findmyfbid.com one look like this:

`1000******00783`

Why is this happening and please let me know how can I open chat head for the specific user?

Comment: Are you trying to open another's user chat with your id?

Comment: `new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("fb-messenger://user/"+AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken().getUserId()));` This line states that you want to view chat of some user which has YOUR userId?

Comment: @MurtazaKhursheedHussain No, I'm not trying to open anybody's chats. I'm trying to send facebook message to him/her.

Comment: `I'm trying to send facebook message to him/her.` where is the message part in intent?

Comment: @MurtazaKhursheedHussain Sorry, I think I misinterpret your reply above. What I'm trying to to is open certain user's chathead and then user can send him a message or I can involve the message part too in the intent.

Comment: sorry but I think you are confused, share you complete code snippet

Comment: `I'm trying to to is open certain user's chathead` you are trying to open certan user chathead with your user id? thats not gonna happen. You are not clear what you want to do.

Comment: @MurtazaKhursheedHussain Sir, I'm clear about what I want to do. I think I'm unable to explain it to you. I'm trying to open certain user's chathead using his/her id not my id. See the code above.

Comment: what is `mProfile` ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157003/discussion-between-hammad-nasir-and-murtaza-khursheed-hussain).

Comment: @MurtazaKhursheedHussain It seems I am still unable to explain you. Please tell me what is unclear here and I'll try to explain my motive more clearly.

Comment: What is the class name of `mProfile`. It would be better if you post your complete code on gist or something.

Comment: @MurtazaKhursheedHussain please come in chat